# Can I say "to get money off (of) someone"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

"To get money off (something)" can be used when talking about deals and discounts, for example:

> You can get money off drinks if you order a full course dinner.

However, can I use the same expression when talking about someone gaining money from someone else? Examples:

> Don't trust everything she says, she's just trying to **get money off** you.

> Don't trust everything she says, she's just trying to **get money off of** you.

Are these two uses correct? If so, which one should be preferred?

Comment: get money off of someone is to get someone's money. gain money is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your examples are technically correct/acceptable. I don't think anyone would misunderstand you. However, I don't think any of them would be preferred when talking about a person.

Whenever someone uses "get money off" when talking about deals/discounts, it usually is meant in the context of "money deducted from a total cost" or "money off the total". To use it when talking about a person is understandable, but it isn't how I suspect most people would phrase it.

I think most people would say "They are just trying to get money **from** you". The money is something you possess and they need to get it from you. If that makes sense.

There is also a less formal, more slang, "They are just trying to get money **out of** you". This slang version has a perceived tone of deception or bad intentions on the part of the person trying to get the money. I believe this comes from an expression, but that is a whole other topic.